# Error while running the existing project on xcode5.1

Tags: ios, iokit, xcode5.1

I have updated my xcode to xcode5.1 and I can't run the existing project now. Below is the error I am getting. I have added the static library within this project. Also I am using external framework, IOKit framework. I don't understand why am I getting this error. It was working perfectly with xcode5.0.2. Error is below:

```
Ld /Users/xxxxx/armv7/xxx normal armv7

cd /Users/xxxx

export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0

export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/xxx-cmjabkmgfntwxeedtebsizdngzry/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/xxx -F/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-cmjabkmgfntwxeedtebsizdngzry/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/xxxcmjabkmgfntwxeedtebsizdngzry/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/armv7/xxx.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -lIOKit -lLIBRARY_TEST -lsqlite3 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreMedia -lxml2.2 -lxml2 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreMotion -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreGraphics -llockdown -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/xxx-cmjabkmgfntwxeedtebsizdngzry/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/armv7/xxx_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/xxx-cmjabkmgfntwxeedtebsizdngzry/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/armv7/xxx
```

Please consider xxx is the path of my project.

```
ld: library not found for -lIOKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried changing all the settings related to Architectures but no luck. Any help appreciated.

Comment: show your full error log

Comment: Set `IOKit framework` to required in `Build phases`

Comment: @Mani - Added whole code for you

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi - How to set IOKIT framework in build phase, As IOKIT framework is external framework. I just add the IOKIT framework folder downloaded from Github to my project.

Comment: @Mani - I have seen many answers but didn't worked any

Answer (score 0):

Manually add **library search path** to your finder where you've added libs.

> Project setting -> Build setting -> library search path ->
>   "../ProjectDirectory/Static library path"

Comment: @Dream removed that reference and add it again and Build clean -> Try.

Comment: Before that, did you change architecture to "Including 64-bit"? or Standard architecture?

Comment: Yes, I tried both of the above, but didn't worked for me